# mySQL Database tables have 2 different prefixes, giving me database connection issues

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I was working on a site, and restored a database and file back-up, and I am getting the "Error Establishing a Database Connection".

When I check the mySQL database, half of the tables are running a 'wsd_' prefix, while the other files are running 'ahc_'.

wp-config currently has 
$table_prefix: 'wsd_'

Is there any way to tell the wp-config file to look for both "wsd_" and "ahc_"?

Sorry ahead of time, as I'm still new to mySQL.

Comment: will I have to rewrite the prefixes to be similar throughout.

Comment: This is just a guess but.... maybe WP only looks at the `wsd_` tables and some other app uses the others. Or it could be an addon/plugin that is using the `ahc_` tables

Comment: @RiggsFolly if WP is only looking for wsd_, how do I proceed to identify the root of the Database Connection issue? I can't imagine another reason other than WP not finding the ahc_ tables, but again, I'm new to mySQL, so an obvious answer may not be as obvious to me...

Comment: Your question says ___I am not getting the "Error Establishing a Database Connection".___ So are you or not???

Comment: So sorry, it has been a rather long day for me, hadn't even realized that I had put "I am not", should be "I am". I edited it for clarity. Thank you for that. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Did you create the database? You have to create a database for the restore to load tables and data into

Comment: I did not manually create one, but was under the impression that when I did a database backup through Updraft Pro (should have specified that I was using this plug-in) that it would handle all of that. Do I need to manually create a new one before I restore a back-up?

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest and reliable method is to export your whole database. Then open database in the notepade or any editor software specially if you have notepad++ or dreamweaver.

Keep one prefix. Suppose you want to keep "ahc_" then find all "wsd_" and replace with "ahc_"

Save the file. Now import that file to your database. All prefix will be same :)